# Can I check the version of the python interpreter required by a python file without running it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, version

I have a simple python file on the desktop. It specifies python2 in the shebang, let's say. Is there anyway for me to `tester.py --version` in the command line without running the file?

As-is, this tells me that the requested version is not installed (expected).

If I change the shebang to specify python3, then `tester.py --version` runs just fine, but doesn't tell me the version.

I wish to know if there is any way to view the version requirements of the specific python script without executing it.

Comment: Of a single script, I expect "no". Requirements can be bundled up in a package but for a script, I don't think so. Happy to be proven wrong

Comment: I would say no?
Dirty gritty way would be to extract the version (2 or 3) specified in the shebang with sed and awk (using bash) or reading the first line of the file, then extracting the last part of the text using `split` or standard library `re` (using python, platform agnostic).